# Как сделать эффект появления прозрачности не всего элемента сразу?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как сделать эффект появления прозрачности не всего элемента сразу?
Например, слева направо или снизу вверх?

Comment: может такой вариант подойдет - http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/vh2e8h7j/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Например, так: http://jsfiddle.net/g7zovv5c/2/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="transparent">content</div>
    <div class="overlay transparent">content</div>
</div>

.transparent {
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: arial;
    opacity: 0.5;
    background-color: red;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.overlay {
    opacity: 1 !important;
    position: relative;
    top: -76px;
}
```

Суть: делаем 2 элемента, один прозрачный, другой нет, помещаем второй поверх первого. После этого мы можем анимировать верхний элемент, показывая часть нижнего, прозрачного. Анимацию можно сделать и на CSS3 Transitions.

Answer (score 2):

Создать 2 слоя, в которых один является прозрачным относительно второго, но не является таковым относительно всего документа. Скриптом прописать перемещение нижнего слоя под прозрачным. Должен получиться ожидаемый эффект.

Answer (score 1):

Для WebKit можно сделать так:

```
.transparency_gradient {
    -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);

}
```

Но в остальных браузерах - пичалька.

Answer (score -1):

В веб-дизайне частичная прозрачность также применяется и достигается за счёт формата цвета RGBA, который задаётся только для фона элемента
http://site-fi.ru/effekt-prozrachnosti-pri-navedenii-na-ssylku/

Comment: Это спам что ли?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение? Добавьте в ответ минимальный необходимый пример решения (информацию по ссылке могут удалить и ответ потеряет ценность).